# spark: open CSV; save as partitioned parquet

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I need to convert a CSV file to a partitioned parquet file. I am unable to find the correct technique to do this. I the CSV in as a DF because the data was exported from a database (SAP HANA) and I am parsing the "create.sql" for the table to auto-create the dataframe. I will process thousands of tables using this technique.

```
var df_sql=s"""CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE CDHDR_MRP_DF (MANDANT VARCHAR(3),
OBJECTCLAS VARCHAR(15) , OBJECTID VARCHAR(90) , CHANGENR VARCHAR(10), 
USERNAME VARCHAR(12) , UDATE VARCHAR(8) , UTIME VARCHAR(6) 
, TCODE VARCHAR(20) , PLANCHNGNR VARCHAR(12) , ACT_CHNGNO VARCHAR(10) 
, WAS_PLANND VARCHAR(1) , CHANGE_IND VARCHAR(1) , LANGU VARCHAR(1) 
, VERSION VARCHAR(3) , _DATAAGING VARCHAR(8)      ) 
USING com.databricks.spark.csv OPTIONS (path "$vCsv")  """
vc.sql(df_sql)
```

I convert this to an RDD, and then save it as Parquet:

```
var rdd=vc.sql(s"""SELECT * from $vDF_Table""")
rdd.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(vOutputPath)
```

This works. 
If I add '.partitionBy("USERNAME")' the error message is

```
<console>:121: error: value partitionBy is not a member of Unit
```

What is the correct technique to convert a CSV to a partitioned parquet file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parquet` executes an action. If you want to partition you have call it before it happens:

```
rdd.write.partitionBy("foo").mode("overwrite").parquet(vOutputPath)
```